# Online Quiz: how can I avoid timer getting refreshed when user click on refresh button in the browser toolbar/Status Bar?

Tags: javascript, timer

```
  htmlTable.Append("<script> var seconds = " + ttime + "; function secondPassed() { var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30) / 60);  var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60; if (remainingSeconds < 10) { remainingSeconds = '0' + remainingSeconds;  } document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'Time Left :- ' + minutes + ':' + remainingSeconds; if (seconds == 0) { clearInterval(countdownTimer);document.getElementById('Button1').click(); } else  { seconds--; } } var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);</script>");
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = htmlTable.ToString() });
```

The above code is used to create a timer in .aspx.cs file. It's an online exam application.

Comment: You can store values in `localStorage` or something, but if it's an online exam you really need a timing mechanism in server-side code.

Comment: what do you mean by timing mechanism in server side code? can you please help me with this sir. It will be a great help if you can sort this out... Please sir.